# MS Project - One year is calculated wrong

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I have two tasks in ms project:

Task A, start: today 03/22/2017
Task B, predecessor: Task A FS+12eMonths
Task A and B are both 0 days long and automatically planned.
Task B start/finish is calculated: Saturday, 03/17/2018

Question 1: Why?
Question 2: What field or project settings would I have to use to achieve the date which I would expect (03/22/2018), without setting it to a manual field?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft seems to have hard-coded 1 emo = 30 edays.  There is no setting to achieve your expected date, which is based on the variable human interpretation of "month."  For workarounds, I would definitely stay away from task mode (i.e. "Manually-scheduled"). You could play with task calendars and/or constraints to force the second task to the date you expect.  In the long run, users of CPM scheduling tools like MSP need to give up on such expectations altogether.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. How would you add a bunch of tasks which definitely take 10 months or 15 months? You won't calculate them on your own or would you?

Comment: I would simply stay away from using months as a unit of time measurement in a project schedule.  Work time is paramount, and calendar months do not have a consistent amount of working time.  Use weeks or days.